# Does YUI have an official irc channel?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, yui, yui3

While the yui3 docs are pretty nice, sometimes it helps to be able to ask the wrong questions to get the best practices.

Is there a hangout for all the cool yui devs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The YUI Project has an official IRC channel, #yui, on Freenode. It typically has 50-60 people in it, and about half of the core team regularly spends time in the channel, as well as several of the more active members of the YUI Forums and gallery contributors.

The channel is largely made up of YUI3 users these days, but it's still possible to get YUI2 help there.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about an irc channel for YUI, but the channel with the most YUI traffic seems to be the YUI Library [Forums](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/). It is accessible from the main YUI [HomePage](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) but it's not a directory or subdomain of the yahoo domain.

YUI Forums gets a fair amount of traffic (about 20 posts per day for the YUI 3 section); in addition, the YUI developers, perhaps not all of them, but at least some of them (in particular Dav Glass) use the Forum to post announcements.

Again, this Forum is subsumed within the YUI Library Site, which is the place to file bug reports, feature requests, view tickets, browse the source, etc.